# Black screen after selecting Openbox

Tags: 15.04, desktop-environments, openbox

After installing Ubuntu 15.04 on my 2GoPC. At the desktop environment menu, I selected Openbox and logged in. Then a black screen appeared with just cursor. I tried right-clicking, but nothing happened.
Since i have auto-login enabled, it will always boot into Openbox.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Can you get to a text terminal using alt-ctrl-F1 ?

Answer (score 1):

When you right click anywhere on the openbox desktop you should get a very small menu.  It is not a normal menu.  You can get a terminal and launch applications from the terminal or you can exit openbox which should bring you to a login page.  To change the cycle choose Lubuntu from the dropdown menu from the fist icon above and login to Lubuntu.  That is how it is supposed to work.  I just checked it.